# Как передать переменную из jquery в отдельный python скрипт?

Tags: python, html, jquery, ajax, flask

Пишу сайт на Flask. Есть jquery обработчик в одном из файлов шаблона html, который обращается к python скрипту и получает от него json данные. На примере так же как и происходит для php скрипта в ajax. Вот как получить результат выполнения py скрипта я сделал, а как отправить в скрипт переменную и считать её там для обработки не пойму. В php есть функция $_POST["var name"], а как подобное реализовать для py ?

Код:

```
#Отправка в python plan_get_stats.py на получение json после обработки:
$.getJSON('engine_scripts/py/plan_get_stats.py',function (data)

#Отправка результата обратно в шаблон из скрипта plan_get_stats py:
print(json.dumps({'данные': 'какие то данные'}))

#Обработка обращения скрипта во Flask:
import subprocess as sp 
 
@app.route('/engine_scripts/py/plan_get_stats.py', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def pyexample(): 
    out = sp.run(["py", "engine_scripts/py/plan_get_stats.py"], stdout=sp.PIPE) 
 
    render_template('scoreboard.html') 
    return out.stdout
```